# Using instrumental variable in a difference-in-differences setup using feols

Tags: difference-in-difference, instrumental-variables

I have the following regression model:

$$y_{ist} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Post_{ist} + \beta2 Post_{ist} \times Distance_{i} + \theta_i + \alpha_t + \gamma_{st} + \epsilon_{ist}
$$

Where,

- $y_{ist}$ is the outcome variable for district $i$ from state $s$ and
  year $t$.
- $Post_{ist}$ is a binary dummy variable equal to 1 if it is
  a year after the treatment is completed. The variable varies at the
  district level.
- $Distance_{i}$ is a continuous variable that denotes the distance from the district
  center to a highway which is constant over time.
- $\theta_i$ is the
  district fixed effects.
- $\alpha_t$ is the year fixed effects.
- $\gamma_{st}$ is the state-by-year fixed effects.
- $\epsilon_{ist}$ is
  the idiosyncratic error term clustered at the district level.

However, due to the endogeneity issues with the $Distance_i$ variable, I instrument it using another variable, $Nodal_i$, which varies by district, is constant over time, and is continuous.

I am trying to estimate this instrumental variable regression with fixed effects using the `feols` command on R. However, I am unsure how to do it with the $Post_{ist}$ and $Post_{ist} \times Distance_{i}$ variables in it. Is the following code correct? Do I use the $Post_{ist}$ variable on both sides of the section where I equate an endogenous variable to an instrument?

```r
iv <- feols(y ~ 1 | district + year + stateyear | post + 
            post*distance ~ post + post*nodal,
            weights = ~district_population_2000, data = df)
```